# Is Personal TeX still in operation? (Seeking updated MathTime Pro 2 fonts.)

Tags: fonts, mtpro

I'm trying to get updated versions of the MathTime Pro 2 fonts from Personal TeX (pctex.com), their publisher.

Are they still in existence?

I've sent email to them several times over the past several months but have heard nothing back except to my first message. That one reply was that an update would be sent to me, but there's been no follow-up.

Any other way to get in touch with them?

Comment: Have you tried calling them on the phone?

Toll Free 800-808-7906
Outside the US: (+1) 415-296-7550
Facsimile (+1) 415-296-7501

Comment: Their website pages say "last updated 2013" or "Copyright 2009." I would interpret that as "it's dead."

Comment: … and apart from one unanswered question in 2017, their is no activity on their forum since 2013 either.

Comment: Just curious: Are you updating from MTP to MTP2, or is there new update for MTP2 itself?

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade MTPro2 Complete to their current versions. A few months ago, I had noticed that the MTPro2 Lite fonts had later dates than the MTPro2 Complete fonts. In an email, Lance Cairnes of Personal TeX said there were newer versions of the Complete set that he would make available. But I've heard no reply to my subsequent emails.

Comment: Ah, I missed your reply because you didn’t “at” me. There were strange things I noticed too. In the Lite version there are accents `\arc` and `\widearc`, but the Complete version doesn’t contain these glyphs (which could explain why the Lite dates are newer than the Complete dates). I am curious to know about the progress you might have made so far…

Comment: @RuixiZhang: No progress to date. I may try the suggestion to phone, but with current shut-downs I don't know whether PCTeX has anybody in an office.